# bash EOF in if statement

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, eof

I am trying to do an action in a IF ELSE statement in Bash, but receive an error like this one:

*Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")*

Now I am quite new to this, so probably the solution to my problem should not be that difficult :)

```
if [ "$DAYNAME" = 'Sunday' ]; then
    echo 'The backup will be uploaded'
    ftp -n $HOST <<EOF
        quote USER $USER
        quote PASS $PASSWD
        put $filetoday
        delete ${filethreeweeksago}
        quit
    EOF
fi
```

Of course the vars are already filled.

I think it has to do with the EOF notation, because when i remove them, the problem disapears. Unfortunatly I don't know how to use the code without the EOF notation.

Can anyone tell me why this error is comming up?

Answer (score 32):

Drop the blanks and it should work:

```
    EOF
^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. Saved so much of time

Answer (score 7):

add a dash to EOF if you want to keep the tabs:
from:

```
ftp -n $HOST <<EOF
```

to:

```
ftp -n $HOST <<-EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1039

> The here document delimiter will not be recognized if it is indented.
>
> You can fix it in one of two ways:
>
> 1.Simply remove the indentation, even though this may break formatting.
>
> 2.Use <<- instead of <<, and indent the script with tabs only (spaces will not be recognized).
>
> Removing the indentation is preferred, since the script won't suddenly break if it's reformatted, copy-pasted, or saved with a different editor.

Comment: True, but doesn't really add anything new that other answers didn't cover yet, does it?

Answer (score 1):

EOL inside If-Else

Syntax of EOL can be this type

```
if [ condition ]; then
    echo "Comment"
else
    cat >> file.txt <<-EOL

    EOL
fi
```