# Bash syntax for if thens

Tags: linux, bash

Having trouble trying to run this from bash :

```
[root@bryanserver ~]# $SPACER="#-------#" APACHE_ENABLED=`ls -1 "$HTTPD_HOSTS-EN" | grep ".conf" | sed s/.conf//` APACHE_COUNT=`echo -e "$APACHE_ENABLED" | wc -1` if [ -n "$APACHE_ENABLED" ]; then echo $SPACER echo "Apache enabled Sites: $APACHE_COUNT" echo "$APACHE_ENABLED" else echo $SPACER echo "There are no detectable nor delectable WebSites In Sight Blackbeard" fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then
```

Is the problem with the code per se or with trying to use it from the shell
rather than having it in a file and sourcing the file?

Entering this on the command line in Bash :

```
APACHE_ENABLED=`"$HTTPD_HOSTS_EN" | grep ".conf" | sed s/.conf//`
APACHE_COUNT=`echo -e "$APACHE_ENABLED" | wc -l`
if [ -n "$APACHE_ENABLED" ]; then
 echo $SPACER
 echo "Apache Enabled Sites: $APACHE_COUNT"
 echo "$APACHE_ENABLED" 
else
 echo $SPACER
 echo "There are no detected Apache Enabled Sites"
fi

produces this output:
APACHE_ENABLED=`"$HTTPD_HOSTS_EN" | grep ".conf" | sed s/.conf//`
APACHE_COUNT=`echo -e "$APACHE_ENABLED" | wc -l`
-bash: : command not found
[root@bryanserver ~]# APACHE_COUNT=`echo -e "$APACHE_ENABLED" | wc -l`
[root@bryanserver ~]# if [ -n "$APACHE_ENABLED" ]; then
>  echo $SPACER
>  echo "Apache Enabled Sites: $APACHE_COUNT"
>  echo "$APACHE_ENABLED"
> else
>  echo $SPACER
>  echo "There are no detected Apache Enabled Sites"
> fi  #
```

and hit enter and voila! this is the result:
There are no detected Apache Enabled Sites
[root@bryanserver ~]#
and Bash is ready to do more work.

So, yes as Keith pointed out, I had mistaken an *ell* for a 1, and there are still some quirks, but it executes and issues a report.  That's progress.

I am working here with some material from Charles Smith; he shared some scripts on GitHub;
github.com/twohlix/HostingScripts/blob/master/listwww.

But I was using NotePad, and after editing some things, when I would put the text on the clipboard and unload it in Bash, what was I believe happening was I was getting the EOF issues.  This SO question gave me an idea:
[bash EOF in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9349616/bash-eof-in-if-statement?rq=1)
I used *View* / *Show Line Endings* in NotePad2, and copied my code, then pasted it
into Bash, that worked.

Comment: I think you mean `SPACER=` not `$SPACER=` at the beginning of the line.  Also, you need either newlines or semicolons to seperate commands in your `if` statement.

Comment: ...and this would probably be easier to debug if you first tried it using multiple lines.

Comment: Once you fix the syntax error(s), I think you'll find you want `wc -l` (lowercase letter ell) rather than `wc -1` (digit one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things I see:

- declaration of `$SPACER` shouldn't have the dollar sign
- add semicolons `;` between declarative statements

I think this is what you mean in a multi-line statement:

```
SPACER="#-------#"
APACHE_ENABLED=`ls -1 "$HTTPD_HOSTS-EN" | grep ".conf" | sed s/.conf//`
APACHE_COUNT=`echo -e "$APACHE_ENABLED" | wc -1`
if [ -n "$APACHE_ENABLED" ]; then 
    echo $SPACER;
    echo "Apache enabled Sites: $APACHE_COUNT";
    echo "$APACHE_ENABLED";
else 
    echo $SPACER;
    echo "There are no detectable nor delectable WebSites In Sight Blackbeard";
fi
```

In one line then, remember to add semicolons or the double ampersand `&&` to separate statements:

```
SPACER="#-------#"; APACHE_ENABLED=`ls -1 "$HTTPD_HOSTS-EN" | grep ".conf" | sed s/.conf//`; APACHE_COUNT=`echo -e "$APACHE_ENABLED" | wc -1`; if [ -n "$APACHE_ENABLED" ]; then echo $SPACER; echo "Apache enabled Sites: $APACHE_COUNT"; echo "$APACHE_ENABLED"; else echo $SPACER; echo "There are no detectable nor delectable WebSites In Sight Blackbeard"; fi
```

Comment: @Keith many thanks.  as things turned out the problem was concerning the attempt to type in manually in bash what was meant to be a file, executed with command [  source filename   ].  I have added some info which may be useful to others.

Comment: @MountainMan: You're thanking me for mzhang's answer; all I did was clean up the formatting.

Comment: @mzhang he's right, my bad. Thanks for getting the ball rolling :)